# Select2 Append Values

Tags: javascript, textbox, coffeescript

I have this code to set the value of a [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) field and update the connected data accordingly.

is it possible to append the data instead?

this way, you could add multiple values by clicking on them one after the other, instead of only once at a time
this is in coffeescript

```
$("#multiValueSelect").val(o.word.toLowerCase()).trigger "change"
```

Comment: Why don't you just get the current value, append the options you want, then set the value?

Comment: uh maybe that's what i'm trying to do? i'm not sure how to append, as that wasn't clear from the select2 page